# Dynamically allocated object C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, memory, dynamic

Hey everyone I got a quick question. I'm getting back into C++ and was wondering about this

If I have dynamically allocated object:

```
MyObject* obj = new MyObject();
```

And it has an array inside as member:

```
class MyObject 
{
public:
   MyObject();
   ~MyObject();
   float array[16];
   private:
};
```

will just doing a normal delete:

```
delete obj;
```

on the object free up all the memory (including the array)? Or do I need to do something special for that?

Comment: Yes, it will. Arrays are no different to other built-in types in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're doing fine. All the memory of the object will be released.

p.s.: If you also dynamically create memory inside the class, you should release their memories inside the destructor `~MyObject()`.

For example:

```
class MyObject
{
public:
    /** Constructor */
    MyObject() : test(new int[100]) {}
    /** Destructor */
    ~MyObject() { delete []test; };  // release memory in destructor 
    /** Copy Constructor */
    MyObject(const MyObject &other) : test(new int[100]){
        memcpy(test, other.test, 100*sizeof(int));
    }
    /** Copy Assignment Operator */
    MyObject& operator= (MyObject other){
        memcpy(test, other.test, 100 * sizeof(int));
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int *test;
};
```

p.s.2: Extra copy constructor and dopy assignment operator are needed to make it follow [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: @juanchopanza What do you mean by *break* (after fixing all syntax issues)?

Comment: See the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).  Imagine what will happen if you copy this class.

Comment: -1 for example of `int* test`, this is a bad idea. Use a container that manages its own memory.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Using `int *test` is just for an illustration of how to manage dynamically-created memory in class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the array is of fixed size and not allocated dynamically then the memory will be released in the destructor of `MyObject`. You might find using `std::array` is a more convenient way of holding a fixed size array:

```
#include <array>

struct MyObject {
  std::array<float, 10> array;
};
```

Also, if you are going to dynamically allocate the memory for `MyObject` I recommend using a smart pointer like `unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>

auto my_object = std::unique_ptr<MyObject>(new MyObject);
//auto my_object = std::make_unique<MyObject>(); // C++14
```

If you want a variable sized, dynamically allocated array I recommend using a `vector`:

```
#include <vector>

struct MyObject {
  std::vector<float> array;
};
```

In which case the memory allocated to the array will be released when the `MyObject` destructor is called.